# Matplotlib Legend not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]I am trying this [example](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists):

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

plt.show()
```

Neither of the 2 plots worked (one trying to show red color or the blue stars). I just get a blank plot with no errors. I did try the examples before this and they work.

Comment: Please show the code you've used.

Comment: The code you have given produces exactly the output of the given examples as expected. It is a blank plot but with a legend: it is very unclear what your issue is?

Comment: @Greg It's not clear but I think the OP means that the legend is not displayed as per the example output. You should get a blank plot with a legend but the OP gets a blank plot with no legend. I also get a blank plot with no legend.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What version of matplotlib are you using? This can be found from running `import matplotlib; matplotlib.__version__` in the interactive prompt. On 1.5.x this example works fine.

Comment: I get a blank plot with No legend. I am not seeing the legend is what the issue is. I am using version 1.3.1

Comment: I see the same behavior in 1.3.1. Looks like you need to upgrade Matplotlib if you want this to work.

Comment: I also can confirm this behavior on mpl-1.3.1.

Comment: That is odd....However, now that 1.4.0 is out there will not be any more bug-fix releases for the 1.3 series.